# Calling Remove button inside append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the script i'm using to append name input field-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
            var someId = document.getElementById('someId').value;
            var name =  document.getElementById('name').value;

            $('.print_box').append('<div class="' + someId + '"> <tr> <td> <input type="button" ref="'+someId+'" class="remove_button" value="Remove"></td>  <td><input type="text"  multiple name="name[]" value="' + name + '" </td>  </tr>

        });
    });

</script>
```

Now I want to call remove button from a separate standalone script like-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".remove_button").click(function() {
            var getRemoveID = $(this).attr('ref');
            $("." + getRemoveID + "").remove();

        });
    });
</script>
```

But this isn't working. It only works when remove function is included with append like-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add").click(function() {
                        var someId = document.getElementById('someId').value;
                        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                        $('.print_box').append('<div class="' + someId + '"> <tr> <td> <input type="button" ref="' + someId + '" class="remove_button" value="Remove"></td>  <td><input type="text"  multiple name="name[]" value="' + name + '" </td>  </tr>



$(".remove_button").click(function() {
                                var getRemoveID = $(this).attr('ref');
                                $("." + getRemoveID + "").remove();
                            });
                        });
                });
</script>
```

Now, How can I seperate those 2 function? i mean calling remove button outside that append script??

Comment: append in your first script is missing its closing parenthesis

Comment: Better use javascript tag(template) **``**, instead of using lots of concatenations of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `on`

```
$("body").on("click", ".button", function() {              
    alert("click")
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxRNjM

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you solve it. You are going in wrong direction. The problem here is that you are trying to handle events for the elements which are being added on the DOM **dynamically**.

So you need to handle events like (`click, mouseover` etc) for those elements in this way

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove_button', function(){
  //Code to handle that event when click on remove_button
});
```